# What is the - at the <% end -%>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently learning ruby-on-rails and I noticed in the tutorial I am following that closing the syntax  <% end %>.

Out of curiosity, I wanted to know why mine is showing <% end -%> with the minus sign before %. The codes are working just fine with the minus sign?

Comment: Please Visit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284421/what-is-the-meaning-of-erb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<% %> and <%- -%> are the same. however that <%= %> and <%= -%> are different: only the latter removes trailing whitespaces.
**Example :**

```
<div>
  <%= "Hii" -%>
</div>
```

It will produce

```
<div>
  Hii</div>
```

and without '-' :

```
<div>
  Hii
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. `<%-` removes leading whitespace. `-%>` removes trailing whitespace. It does not matter if the tag yields.

Comment: You should do some practical with that and please give some example so i can try.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% end -%>
```

is used to avoid line break after expression